# How do i retrieved selected drop-down list value to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015

The MVC approach is giving me difficulty to understand how i actually retrieve data.

**View**

```
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("About"))
    {
        <span style="margin-top: 1em; float: right;">
            Filter Zone Area @Html.DropDownList("ZoneArea", new SelectListItem[]
            {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "All", Value = "0" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "North", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "South", Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "East", Value = "3" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "West", Value = "4" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Central", Value = "5" },},
            new { @onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
        </span>

    }
</p>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult About(School model, FormCollection form)
{
      string strDDLValue = form["ZoneArea"]; 

      var schooList = schGateway.SelectAll();
      schooList = schooList.Where(s => s.Zone_Id == 1);

      if (schooList != null)
      {
          foreach (var school in schooList)
          {
              string[] schLoc = new string[] { school.School_Name, school.Dus_Lat.ToString(), school.Dus_Long.ToString() };
              model.SchooList.Add(schLoc);
          }
      }

      return View(model);
}
```

When i debug this code below it return me null value

```
string strDDLValue = form["ZoneArea"];
```

Comment: Everything your doing here is bad practice. Build you `SelectList` in the controller, not the view. Bind your dropdownlist to a model property (is `ZoneArea` a property in your model?) and post back your model - do not use `FormCollection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in the code. I am able to get the value by using exactly same code in both view and controller. Just the difference is in @using (Html.BeginForm("About","Default")) where Default is controller name. also if we use Request.Form["ZoneArea"] then we can get rid of FormCollection parameter in action.

The solution given by Stephen Muecke in the comment is the correct way but here I am just saying that there is no error for getting value in the controller from view in your code.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.SelectList = GetDict();

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        string strDDLValue = Request.Form["ZoneArea"];
        ViewBag.SelectedValue = strDDLValue;
        ViewBag.SelectList = GetDict();
        return View("Index");
    }

    public Dictionary<string,int> GetDict()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dict.Add("All", 0);
        dict.Add("North", 1);
        dict.Add("South", 2);
        dict.Add("East", 3);
        dict.Add("West", 4);
        dict.Add("Central", 4);

        return dict;
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("About","Default"))
{
    <span style="margin-top: 1em; float: right;">
        Filter Zone Area @Html.DropDownList("ZoneArea", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectList,"value","key",ViewBag.SelectedValue),
        new { @onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
    </span>

}
```

Comment: thanks, one question on how to keep the selected value selected after it redirects? my issue now is that the page reloads and the selectedvalue in the dropdown regenerates